# Is there any web service for getting tidal information outside the US?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-services

Has anyone come across a web service or plugin/code/calculation for getting information on tides - namely high and low tide times?
I only need this information for one location (outside the US) but I need it on an ongoing basis so a web service that I can hit once a day or something would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NOAA Weather Service](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/noaa-weather-service)

Comment: As comment above, I'm looking for a service that covers outwith the US, thanks.